# Persist redux nested state changes to local storage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I have been following the tutorial to make redux state persist to the local storage.
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage

However, what if I create my store like this with reducers:

```
 const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState)
```

And the root reducer is a combined reducers of:

```
 const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: AuthStore,
    content: contentReducer,
    pages: pageReducer,
 }
```

And each reducer has its own state/initialState, for example contentReducer is constructed as below:

```
const initialState = {selected, search}
const contentReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch (action) {
     case SELECT :   
       return {
         ...state,
         selected: action.payload
     case SEARCH: 
       return {
         ...state,
         search: action.payload
       }
   }
 }
```

If I follow the tutorial, then I can do

```
 const saveSelected = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedSelected = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('selected', serializedSelected)
    } catch (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
 }
 store.subscribe(() => {
    saveSelected(store.getState().content.selected)
 })
```

However since I have many more reducers (I am only giving some examples above)and thus there are many actions dispatched to the store, I don't want the store to keep firing subscribe function everytime when any action is dispatched. I only want the store to subscribe to changes when the particular `store.getState().content.selected` is updated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Redux middleware, which lets you register a function that's being called on each `dispatch`. You get a reference to the store object, so that you can check `store.getState().content.selected` state and act accordingly. See more details and examples [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#the-final-approach).